# How to give csv file as input to movesense simulator

Tags: visual-studio, csv, simulator, movesense

I am new to movesense I am trying to input a csv file to the sample files given in the movesense repository. Can somenone please show me how to do that.Here are the relevent documentations.

http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/

http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/sensor_simulator/

https://www.movesense.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/INTRO-TO-MOVESENSE-DEMO-SCRIPT.txt

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add your csv file in the working directory with the correct format of column name based on the type of system that you are using on the simulator and the simulator will automatically start accepting data from there.

http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/sensor_simulator/

Review the above link for more details.

Thank you